# Search a string for a specific word, then change it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number of  tags which have title's that specify both a contract type and the contract provider.

What I am trying to do is take the title tag and store it within an array and replace all with dashs.

Problem is, there is a a specific format which the contract type has to be stored in. At the moment 'payg' is correct, but because of how it is marked up I don't know how to replace the 'pay monthly' with 'paym'

Please find my code here: http://jsbin.com/ikumar/4/edit/

I don't have access to the markup too.

B

Comment: Always make sure and post your code here as well. These questions are for future reference and that link might not always be there.

Comment: You want to replace the *`title`* of the element with dashes?

Comment: Where is `.info` class in the example, if you use: `var $anaLinks = $('a')` works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$anaLinksTitle = $anaLinksTitle.toLowerCase()
                 .replace(/ /g, '-')
                 .replace('pay-monthly', 'paym');
```

Comment: np, please consider upvoting and/or accepting this answer if it helped you out

Answer (score 1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

```
$anaLinksTitle = $this.attr('title').replace("pay monthly", "paym");
```